# Java String replace multiple strings before Boolean.parseBoolean in Scanner?

Tags: java, string, replace, java.util.scanner

I am building a java program that tracks bowel function for users. I have a segment of code inside a loop that queries the user via Scanner to answer if they have cramps. I have the following code working:

```
String cramps = userInput.nextLine();
String replacecramps = cramps.replace("Y","true");
boolean mycramps = Boolean.parseBoolean(replacecramps);
```

This effectively takes a "Y" answer and replaces it with "true" and then takes the String "true" and changes it to a boolean true (I think - it seems to be working that way, anyway). However, I'd like to change other possible common inputs, such as "y", "yes", "Yes", "yeah", "Yeah", "yep", "Yep", etc as well.

Is there any way to do this? I am very new to Java, so it is proving to be difficult. I have read every single post about it here, and I'm still lost as to how to best go about this.

Here are some code snippets that may be useful:

The branch of the loop this resides in is (I can paste in the full code if necessary, but it is very long):

```
} else if (myBristol == 7) {
   System.out.println("You appear to have severe diarrhea. ");
    //Integrate Diarrhea.java class
    System.out.println("\nDid you experience cramps or bloating? (Y/N)");
    String cramps = userInput.nextLine();
    String replacecramps = cramps.replace("Y","true");
    boolean mycramps = Boolean.parseBoolean(replacecramps);
    System.out.println("Did you experience flatulence? (Y/N)");
    String gas = userInput.nextLine();
    String replacegas = gas.replace("Y","true");
    boolean mygas = Boolean.parseBoolean(replacegas);
    Diarrhea b = new Diarrhea(poopColor, poopSize, mycramps, mygas);
    //Print data to log file
    pw.println(b.toString());
```

The subclasses it is using:

```
public class Poop{
    protected String color;
    protected String size;

    public Poop(String poopColor, String poopSize)
    {
    color=poopColor;
    size=poopSize; 
    }
    public void setcolor(String c)
    {
        color = c;
    }
    public String getcolor(){
        return color;
    }
    public void setsize(String s)
    {
        size = s;
    }
    public String getsize(){
        return size;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String tmp = "This poop's color was: " + this.getcolor() + ". Poop was: " + this.getsize() + ".";
        return tmp;
    }
```

}

```
public class Diarrhea extends Poop{
protected boolean cramps;
protected boolean gas;

public Diarrhea(String poopColor, String poopSize, boolean cramps, boolean gas) {
super(poopColor,poopSize);
this.cramps=cramps;
this.gas=gas;
}
public void setcramps(boolean mycramps) {
    cramps=mycramps;
}
public boolean getcramps(){
    return cramps;
}
public void setgas(boolean gas) {
    gas=this.gas;
}
public boolean getgas(){
    return gas;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    String tmp = "This diarrhea's color was: " + this.getcolor() + ". Was this a little or a lot of diarrhea: " + this.getsize() + ". Did you experience cramps or bloating? (true/false) " + this.cramps + ". Did you experience flatulence? (true/false) " + this.gas + ".";
    return tmp;
}
```

}

This is how I have been managing my y/n questions up until this point, which has been working nicely as it only looks for a y or n as the first character, doesn't care what case, and doesn't care about anything else (like typos). It was a little difficult figuring out how to get it to work for a boolean, but I think I'm on the right path - but maybe I'm going about this all wrong.

```
char answer1 = userInput.next().charAt(0);
    answerString = Character.toString(answer1);
    userInput.nextLine(); 
     if (answerString.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
        //Integrate Poop.java class
        System.out.println("Was this a large, medium, small, or average sized bowel movement (describe size): ");
        String poopSize = userInput.nextLine();
        System.out.println("How would you describe the color of this poop (brown, greenish, light, dark, etc): ");
        String poopColor = userInput.nextLine();
        Poop a = new Poop(poopColor, poopSize);
        //Print data to log file
        pw.println(a.toString());
```

Comment: Where does the input come from? The regex is a good idea but if you know the possible values beforehand you can force the input to some degree (like by using a select field or radio buttons). At that point, accept only known "good" values as true. Same to be said of plain text input--type Y or N--it's pretty hard to think of all possible answers so it may be more practical to make a whitelist.

Comment: @william burnham Currently it's coming from a Scanner in console. I dont know how to do GUIs yet, but once I learn them, much of this program's code will be converted to checkboxes, for sure! They are mostly yes/no questions, so checkboxes would be ideal. I'll get there someday, but I'm not there yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a case insensitive replace all using the list of positive words you want to target:

```
String target = "Dogs Yes yes Yeah yeah Yep yep false";
target = target.replaceAll("(?i)\\b(y|yes|yeah|yep)\\b", "true");
System.out.println(target);

Dogs true true true true true true false
```

### Demo

Comment: This Works! Thanks!

Comment: Now, to figure out how to do the "false" ones for No, NO, no, N, n.

Comment: I think you can adapt my answer for this.

Comment: Yep, got it all working today, thanks @Tim Biegeleisen

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replaceALL` with some regex like this :

```
String input = "you are saying : y yes Yes yeah Yeah yep Yep";
input = input.replaceAll("\\b(?i)y(es|eah|ep)?\\b", "true");

System.out.println(input); //you are saying : true true true true true true true
```

---

details about regex :

- `\b` for Word Boundaries
- `(?i)` for case insensitive
- `y(es|eah|ep)?` y followed by one of (`es` or `eah` or `ep`) which are optional `?`